# Possible to use thrift in a mysql plugin?

Tags: mysql, plugins, thrift

I'm using Mysql 5.5 and the plugin need to query a thrift interfaced server for some information.  I created the thrift client which basically opens a connection to the server, gets a status, and then closes the connection:

```cpp
#include "../../xxxx/gen-cpp/Xxxx.h"
#include <transport/TSocket.h>
#include <transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

using namespace ::za::co::xxxx;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  boost::shared_ptr<TSocket> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

  XxxxServiceClient client(protocol);
  transport->open();
  client.getStatus();
  transport->close();

  return 0;
}
```

I then changed main() to a function name and added it into the plugin code file and called it from the main function.
The plugin code builds fine but the map now contains a whole lot of thrift references and on trying to load the plugin, I get this error:

`ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/libxxxx.so' (errno: 13 undefined symbol: _ZTVN6apache6thrift9transport18TBufferedTransportE)`

Is there any way to get these new thrift references resolved on installing the plugin? It installs and runs fine without the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Thrift cpp tutorial code I was able to create a simple hello world MySQL daemon plugin which made a client call to CppServer process:

```cpp
#include <mysql/plugin.h>
#include <mysql_version.h>

#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <transport/TSocket.h>
#include <transport/TTransportUtils.h>

#include "gen-cpp/Calculator.h"

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

using namespace tutorial;
using namespace shared;

using namespace boost;

static int hello_world_plugin_init(void *p) {

  shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 9090));
  shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));

  CalculatorClient client(protocol);

  transport->open();
  client.ping();
  transport->close();

  return 0;
}
```

And this Makefile:

```
BOOST_DIR = /usr/include/boost
MYSQL_DIR = /usr/include/mysql
THRIFT_DIR = /usr/local/include/thrift
LIB_DIR = /usr/local/lib

GEN_SRC = gen-cpp/SharedService.cpp gen-cpp/shared_types.cpp gen-cpp/tutorial_types.cpp gen-cpp/Calculator.cpp
DEFS = -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H

default: hello_thrift.cc
    g++ ${DEFS} -fPIC -shared -o libhellothrift.so -I${MYSQL_DIR} -I${THRIFT_DIR} -I${BOOST_DIR} -Igen-cpp -L${LIB_DIR} hello_thrift.cc ${GEN_SRC} -lthrift
```

This is just example code and will crash your MySQL server if Thrift CppServer isn't running.

I tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using gcc 4.6.3, MySQL 5.5.24, Thrift 0.8.0, Boost 1.46